# Identifying the index of a specific value in a list to append whilst in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

Background context - I am using the mailchimp3 python library, I am trying to retrieve a series of actions that a person may have had with an email they have received. Generally, it's either bounced, opened or clicked. A person can click multiple times, open it multiple times, or it will just bounce and that's the end of it.

What I am trying to do is to identify 
1. If a there was a click vs. an open, what is the index value of the 'click' within a list of the actions they took. 
2. Pipe in the index value of that click to retrieve the timestamp of the click
3. If there was no click, just take the last action they have taken.

Right now, I have this setup just to take the last action someone has made.I am trying to use for loops (in the middle of the code below) to cycle through their list of actions, identify if they have clicked, prioritize that as the appended value for their action otherwise I will take their last action,

```
def patient_performance(campaign_id):
    campaign_data = client.reports.email_activity.all(campaign_id=campaign_id, get_all=True)

    patient_campaign = []
    patient_email    = []
    patient_activity = []
    activity_time    = []
    action_list      = []

    for value in campaign_data['emails']:
        #For any unopened or untouched emails. The list will return as empty. Removes any empty email results.
        if len(value['activity']) == 0:
            pass

        else:
            try:
                patient_campaign.append(campaign_id)
                patient_email.append(value['email_address'])

                #Previous code that was working
                #patient_activity.append(value['activity'][-1].get('action'))
                #activity_time.append(value['activity'][-1].get('timestamp'))

                #HERE IS THE NEW CODE I AM TRYING TO INCORPORATE!!!!

                #Summarizes the list of various actions a patient has taken with emails.
                for actions in value['activity']:
                    action_list.append(actions.get('action'))
                    timestamp_list.append(actions.get('timestamp'))


                #Attempting to identify the if a patient clicked.
                for counter, value in enumerate(action_list):
                    if  value == 'click':
                        patient_activity.append(value)
                        activity_time.append(value['activity'][counter].get('timestamp'))
                    else:
                        patient_activity.append(value['activity'][-1].get('action'))
                        activity_time.append(value['activity'][-1].get('timestamp'))


            #Catches any errors.
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    #Appends all results captured for specific campaign. This is fed into a temporary DF which is then appended into the master DF. 
    temp_patient_performance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(patient_campaign, patient_email, patient_activity, activity_time)), columns = ['campaign', 'email_address','activity','timestamp'])
    temp_patient_performance = temp_patient_performance.drop(temp_patient_performance[(temp_patient_performance['activity'] == 'bounce')].index)

    print("Retrieved {} patient email results for campaign {}".format(len(temp_patient_performance['email_address']),campaign_id))
    return  temp_patient_performance
```

This is what a sample readout of the results looks like. Each list represents one person, multiple dictionaries within that list represents multiple actions made.

```
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T18:24:19+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T13:43:45+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T00:25:33+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T20:19:00+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T20:36:21+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-04T03:07:53+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T20:45:39+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T23:39:32+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T22:16:54+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T20:14:48+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T22:21:33+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T00:40:15+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T00:54:15+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-04T01:51:53+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T23:54:49+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'bounce', 'type': 'hard', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00'}]
[{'action': 'bounce', 'type': 'hard', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T00:00:00+00:00'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-01T20:28:11+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
[{'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-02T18:27:28+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-03T22:35:34+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-06T20:28:34+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-10T02:32:38+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}, {'action': 'open', 'timestamp': '2019-11-11T05:18:34+00:00', 'ip': '1234'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out through some other posts dedicated to searching for a value in a list of dictionaries.

This in particular is the new code that solved my issue:

```
try:
    patient_activity.append(next(item for item in value['activity'] if item['action'] == 'click').get('action'))
    activity_time.append(next(item for item in value['activity'] if item['action'] == 'click').get('timestamp'))

#StopIteration is returned by the code above where 'click' is not found because a patient has not clicked.

except StopIteration:
        patient_activity.append(value['activity'][-1].get('action'))
        activity_time.append(value['activity'][-1].get('timestamp'))
```

The full code block is below

```
def patient_performance(campaign_id):
    campaign_data = client.reports.email_activity.all(campaign_id=campaign_id, get_all=True)

    patient_campaign = []
    patient_email    = []
    patient_activity = []
    activity_time    = []
    action_list      = []
    timestamp_list   = []
    total_opens      = []
    total_clicks     = []

    for value in campaign_data['emails']:
        #For any unopened or untouched emails. The list will return as empty. Removes any empty email results.
        if len(value['activity']) == 0:
            pass

        else:
            try:
                patient_campaign.append(campaign_id)
                patient_email.append(value['email_address'])

                #Looks to identify which patients have 'clicked', prioritising their click action vs. all else (open or bounce). Otherwise takes their last action.
                try:
                    patient_activity.append(next(item for item in value['activity'] if item['action'] == 'click').get('action'))
                    activity_time.append(next(item for item in value['activity'] if item['action'] == 'click').get('timestamp'))

                #StopIteration is returned by the code above where 'click' is not found because a patient has not clicked.
                except StopIteration:
                    patient_activity.append(value['activity'][-1].get('action'))
                    activity_time.append(value['activity'][-1].get('timestamp'))

            #Catches any errors returned by missing data within the 'activity' list retrieved from Mailchimp.
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    #Appends all results captured for specific campaign. This is fed into a temporary DF which is then appended into the master DF once it's returned to the function call. 
    temp_patient_performance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(patient_campaign, patient_email, patient_activity, activity_time)), columns = ['campaign', 'email_address','activity','timestamp'])
    temp_patient_performance = temp_patient_performance.drop(temp_patient_performance[(temp_patient_performance['activity'] == 'bounce')].index)

    print("Retrieved {} patient email results for campaign {}".format(len(temp_patient_performance['email_address']),campaign_id))
    return  temp_patient_performance
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your requirements, but I believe that this should work?

```py
# HERE IS THE NEW CODE I AM TRYING TO INCORPORATE!!!!

# Summarizes the list of various actions a patient has taken with emails.
for action in value['activity']:
    if action['action'] == 'click':
        patient_activity.append(action['action'])
        activity_time.append(action['timestamp'])

if not len(patient_activity):
    patient_activity.append(value['activity'][-1]['action'])
    activity_time.append(value['activity'][-1]['timestamp'])
```

Comment: This was a good stab at it! It didn't work fully as it would not differentiate between all the various lists (or at least that's what I could tell by the results of adding these in)

Comment: @Grygger Glad you figured it out! It wasn't completely clear what you were trying to accomplish, in the future if you provide an expected output it might make it easier for others to understand the requirements.

Comment: That's a good point Bison! I will make sure to give the input and output to help clarify things,